# R: Converting the Following Code to DPLYR

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I have the following table:

```
age=18:29
height=c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7,79.9,81.1,81.2,81.8,82.8,83.5)
gender=c("M","F","M","M","F","F","M","M","F","M","F","M")
testframe = data.frame(age=age,height=height,height2=height,gender=gender,gender2=gender)

head(testframe)

  age height height2 gender gender2
1  18   76.1    76.1      M       M
2  19   77.0    77.0      F       F
3  20   78.1    78.1      M       M
4  21   78.2    78.2      M       M
5  22   78.8    78.8      F       F
6  23   79.7    79.7      F       F
```

In the above table, I want to remove columns that have identical entries but have different names. This can be done as follows (in Base R):

```
no_dup = testframe[!duplicated(as.list(testframe))]

 head(no_dup)
  age height gender
1  18   76.1      M
2  19   77.0      F
3  20   78.1      M
4  21   78.2      M
5  22   78.8      F
6  23   79.7      F
```

**My Question:** Does anyone know how to convert the above code  `testframe[!duplicated(as.list(testframe))` into "DPLYR" commands? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can pipe it: `testframe %>% filter(. %>% as.list %>% duplicated %>% \`!\`)`, but this is a case where it makes sense to use the data frame as a `list`, and `dplyr` is for working data frames, not lists.

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: Thank you for your reply! I will try this!

Comment: But I'll point out the code in my comment is somewhat tongue-in-cheek. Other than piping (most of which is still nested!) the only change is replacing `[` with `filter`.

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: Thank you for your reply! Why do you think the code in your comment in "somewhat tongue-in-cheek:? I am not sure what you mean in the second sentence - if you have time, can you please show me what replacement you are referring to? Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code and got the following error: testframe %>% filter(. %>% as.list %>% duplicated %>% `!`)
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `. %>% as.list %>% duplicated %>% `!``.
x Input must be a vector, not a <fseq/function> object.

Comment: Do you know what could be causing this error? Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, I guess the `.` doesn't work that way. My "tongue-in-cheek" comment is because almost all I did was change `!duplicated(as.list())` to `as.list %>% duplicated %>% \`!\``, which still doesn't use any `dplyr` functions. So it's using piping from the `magrittr` package, but the only `dplyr` function I (attempted) to use was `filter`.

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: Thank you for your reply! I will keep trying to find a way to solve this in the meantime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `tidyverse`. I used `purrr::map` to convert each column into a list, then I found the lists that were not duplicated. For `dplyr::select`, you cannot use a logical vector, so we can use `which` to return only the `TRUE` columns (i.e., not duplicated). Then, we can use the index value to select the columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

testframe %>%
  dplyr::select(., which(purrr::map(., c) %>%
                           duplicated(.) %>%
                           `!`))
```

Output

```
   age height gender
1   18   76.1      M
2   19   77.0      F
3   20   78.1      M
4   21   78.2      M
5   22   78.8      F
6   23   79.7      F
7   24   79.9      M
8   25   81.1      M
9   26   81.2      F
10  27   81.8      M
11  28   82.8      F
12  29   83.5      M
```

You could also do it without `purrr`.

```
testframe %>%
  dplyr::select(., which(as.list(.) %>%
                           duplicated %>%
                           `!`))
```

Just for fun, here I only use `tidyverse` (though much more verbose). It also requires pivoting the dataframe multiple times.

```
testframe %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  dplyr::mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = rowname, values_from = value) %>%
  dplyr::distinct_at(vars(-name), .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "rowname", values_to = "value") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
  dplyr::select(-rowname)
```

Data

```
testframe <-
  structure(
    list(
      age = 18:29,
      height = c(76.1, 77, 78.1, 78.2,
                 78.8, 79.7, 79.9, 81.1, 81.2, 81.8, 82.8, 83.5),
      height2 = c(76.1,
                  77, 78.1, 78.2, 78.8, 79.7, 79.9, 81.1, 81.2, 81.8, 82.8, 83.5),
      gender = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M",
                 "F", "M"),
      gender2 = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M",
                  "F", "M", "F", "M")
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -12L)
  )
```

Comment: @ Andrew Gillreath-Brown : Thank you so much for your answer! I passed your code through "DBPLYR" command: flights <- copy_to(con, testframe)
 ; flights %>% 
    dplyr::select(., which(as.list(.) %>%
                               duplicated %>%
                               `!`)) %>% show_query()

Comment: This returns the following SQL statement corresponding to the code you wrote (for some reason, the "gender" variable is missing): SELECT `age`, `height`
FROM `testframe`

Comment: Ultimately, I want to use this code on a table located on a server:

Comment: library(RODBC);
library(sqldf);

con = odbcConnect("some name", uid = "some id", pwd = "abc");


sample_query = sqlQuery(con, "SELECT age, height FROM testframe")

Comment: Now the question is: can the code you wrote be used on tables located on a server? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @stats555 I just added another possibility (though it is much more verbose). Essentially, it requires pivoting the data multiple times, which allows for being able to use `dplyr::distinct` rather than using `duplicated`. It might have a better conversion to `DBPLYR`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ Andrew Gillreath-Brown : Thank you so much! I will take a look at it!